# Unable to run on the project using WebLogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jdeveloper

I'm using jdeveloper 11 and developing an application using EJB 3.0 and JSP.

When I tried to run my session bean I get an error saying:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ../modules/org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar

Why am I getting this error? and how could I solve this issue?

```
*** Using HTTP port 7101 ***
*** Using SSL port 7102 ***
C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper>
C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.1.38.60.81\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b50)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore2686588032534698066.jks -javaagent:../modules/org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar -Doracle.jdeveloper.adrs=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1 -Djrockit.optfile=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1\servers\DefaultServer\tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -Dwsm.repository.path=C:\Users\BOTOEO\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.81\DEFAUL~1\oracle\store\gmds   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ../modules/org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar
Process exited.
```

Comment: Things to check:  1) That the jar exists in the first place.  2) That you can open it with a zip program (to prove it isn't corrupt).  3) That it has a manifest in it.  I don't know much about jdeveloper, but that's where I would start.

Comment: @Todd .jar exists. but when i right click on it does not show an option to extract it. (I have installed winRAR). what does manifest mean? is it a file or something else? what does it provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very big effort i could figure how to solve this issue. Go to your workspace and choose open up the folder that is related to ur project current u working on or this issue occurring project. Under this folder or under your current projects folder you will able to see a .jar file, a folder with your application, etc. Now open the application folder. within that application  folder you will be able to see a .jar with the same application name. Open this .jar file with an editor such as notepad or notepad++ . now search for hash area named "RunConfigurations". and remove everything between the start and end tags of "RunConfiguration". NOw restart the jdeveloper and run agian. now ur project start to run.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the folders under `C:\Users\<currentuser>\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper` this folder and restart JDevelper.